# How to display this images inline?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, haml

I'm struggling with this for over an hour. 
I want images in classes "up" and "down" to display inline.
What am I overlooking?

I tried also display:inline, but it's also doesn't work.
If it is helpful I am also using twitter bootstrap with rails.

## pages.css

```
  body {
  background-color: grey;
}




.up img {

  width: 30px;
  height:30px;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  display:inline-block;
}
.down img{
  width: 30px;
  height:30px;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

## index.html.haml

```
  - title "Demociaki"
- for demot in @demots
  .demot
    = image_tag demot.photo.url
    %br
    .voting
      .up= link_to image_tag("up.jpeg"), vote_up_demot_path(demot), :method => :post
      .down= link_to image_tag('down.jpeg'), vote_down_demot_path(demot), :method => :post
      %h3= demot.votes_for
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `img.up` and `img.down` not `up img` and `down img`.

`.up img` is selecting all img elements under an element with the class `.up`.
`img.up` selects all elements with the class `.up` whose tag is `img`.

Comment: Sorry it's not that. That doesn't solve my problem with displaying inline.

Comment: Can you link the page? Or post a copy in a fiddle?

Comment: I can't it's not yet in production.

Comment: The problem lies I didn't give my images proper classes. I only made divs around them. So yours advice was kinda helpful for me:D